# .htaccess rewriterule not working (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in desperate need of some help here. I've been pulling my hair out for over a week now regarding this issue. I know that it should be incredibly straight forward, but for some reason it just doesn't work...

I have a search query that I would like to make to look pretty for aesthetic and seo reasons. I want /rentals to be internally redirected to the (ugly) query /?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true. Just to clarify here, I want visitors not to notice that when they visit /rentals, that they are actually being redirected to the query.

Anyway, I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^rentals/?$ https://www.example.com/?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true [L]
```

Now here example.com is obviously not the actual url. I have tried the above and many minor variations of it including: only the query and not full url; different flags; with and without RewriteEngine On; with and without RewriteBase; trying to redirect not to a query but to a regular page; and probably some other things that I forgot about.

Now it is also worth mentioning that this website runs on Wordpress. The above rewriterule is placed above Wordpress' section in the .htaccess, but that doesn't work either.

If you would like me to provide more info, please let me know!

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**
To answer @msg questions:
I should have mentioned this in my initial question. The RewriteRule mentioned above, does redirect to the correct page. However it is an external rewrite. In other words, when visitings /rentals it does redirect to https://www.example.com/?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true, but it shows the redirect as the url and thus doesn't show /rentals as the url. The goal is to make it an internal rewrite, so that when someone visits /rentals, it actually shows /rentals as the url, and not the redirect.

I have also tried the [R] flag, which Apache's website says is the right flag to use for internal rewrites: [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). But this still results in an external rewrite.

The query is not handled by Wordpress. The PHP file that handles the homepage checks, if there is a search query present and if so, it shows the output of the PHP file that handles search results.

To answer @shane questions:
The answer I gave to one of @msg questions above might help answer your questions too. But to expand on that, rentals is actually not a custom post type. It is a taxonomy for a custom post type called 'listings'.

```
function add_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^rentals/?$', 'https://www.redcapper.com/?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I have tried hooking into Wordpress' rewrite API using the above, but it doesn't work... It gives me a 404 error...

Comment: The problem. What's the problem? Does nothing at all ? Does the url change ? 404 ? And the query is handled by wordpress itself ?

Comment: Marnix.hoh can you provide more information about how the custom post type for rentals is created and searched? I will amend my answer in light of your response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It really means the world to me! @shane I have made an edit to my question in which I answer your questions. Again please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to provide more information on.

Comment: @msg I have also added answers to your questions in my edit. Thank you so much for your help!! Let me know if you would like me to expand on something a little more

Comment: @Marnix.hoh I've updated my answer - give that a shot and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting of WordPress URLs should not be done in .htaccess - WordPress itself implements it's own rewriting engine.

All rewriting should be done with this API. See [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

**EDIT**
Try this...

```
function add_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^rentals/?$', 'index.php?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn't work either, it redirects me to the homepage. Please see my comments to @ msg, they might help with understanding what's going on and more importantly, how my homepage detects and handles (search) queries. You will see from my comments that the search query is not handled directly by wordpress and thus my guess is that wordpress doesn't recognize it and thus defaults to the homepage. Please let me know what your thoughts are and know that I really appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: I would say you are correct. Change `if (!empty($_GET['search-listings']))` to `if (get_query_var('search-listings'))` and ensure that the search-listings template also uses get_query_var.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with also let the search-listings template use get_query_var? Do you mean that every time $_GET is used, it should be replaced with get_query_var? Changing what you suggested and adding the tag using add_rewrite_tag redirects me to a Wordpress search results looking page. Anyway, isn't it possible to just use .htaccess to do the rewrite? I mean it kinda works except that the 'ugly' query is shown in the url bar instead of /rentals. Again thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Marnix, yes that is what I mean. If you use $_GET instead of get_query_var, then rewritten get parameters will not work. There are a multitude of reasons not to do the rewriting in .htaccess - for example, you may have a security plugin that will overwrite your rewrite rules. Wordpress has this functionality built in, all that needs to be done is to update your template now then it should all work - you're on the home stretch now!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I might try that in the future. The thing is, that the way the variables are handled to prepare the (database/wordpress) query is quite complicated (and not written by me)... So I will need to sit down and make sure that it doesn't affect the overall working of the code. I wish that just editing the .htaccess file, would do it. But I guess it doesn't... Again, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but you can't do that (as far as I know). External Redirects are exactly that: Redirects. Masking only works with internal redirects. According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the
>   hostname matches the current host. *[...]*
>   **Otherwise, an external redirect is performed** for the given URL

So, whether or not you specify the `[R]` flag, if the target domain is not the same, it **always** results in the URL on the browser bar changing.

You can Redirect to the new domain with:

```
# [R] not necessary, being implied by the external redirect
RewriteRule ^(rentals)/?$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This will result in a redirection, but the browser bar will show `http://example.com/rentals` instead of the query string one. In the target system you already have a wordpress `rewrite_rule` so that should work.

This is a compromise between what you currently have and what you want.

What you are really trying to do is *proxy* a request, and `mod_rewrite` on its own can't do it. It is not as straightforward as you may think, there are many security considerations where the client might not trust the target system, or there are session cookies or other potential information disclosure involved.

However, if the *middle ground* is not acceptable, you could look into [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy.html). There's support for proxying requests with `mod_rewrite` and the [`[P]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) but you have that prerequisite. But that's a setup I haven't used and can't help much more with.

If you can modify the code you could consider scrapping the target page, but that looks like too much work.

Lastly, you can just embed the target page in your current one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and in-depth reply @msg. However, I am not redirecting to another domain. The target domain is the same. In other words, someone would go to https://www.example.com/rentals and should be redirected to https://www.example.com/?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true. So the domain is the same and thus an internal rewrite should be possible no?

Comment: @Marnix.hoh Then this is not a `mod_rewrite` issue, looks strictly like a wordpress issue, but since you said the query is not handled by wp, I'm a bit lost on what your setup is. Where's your "homepage checks" script ? If it is indeed handled by wordpress you *should* be able to do it with the stock `RewriteRule` and `add_rewrite_rule`, try changing your target to `'index.php?ct_ct_status=for-rent&search-listings=true'` and flushing your rules in `Settings > Permalinks > Save`.

Comment: This unfortunately this doesn't work... It just redirects me to the homepage. There is a php file that 'creates' the homepage. At the top of that php file is code checking if 'search-listings' is a set GET variable. If so, it redirects to the 'search page'. Does that make sense? Please let me know if you want me to elaborate. Again thank you so much for your help

Comment: Yes, please. With the WordPress default `RewriteRules`, any request to non existent files goes to Wordpress' `index.php`. So `/?ct_ct...` will get redirected to `index.php?ct_ct...` but you say that the homepage script isn't a wordpress page. Have you modified `index.php` ? What does this 'checker' script do?

Comment: The homepage uses a 'template' So the Wordpress page that functions as the homepage has the template 'home' assigned to it. In other words, the home template php file has the following comment at the top of the file:
`/**
 * Template Name: Home
 */`
Right below this comment in the same file is the following code:
`if (!empty($_GET['search-listings'])) {
 get_template_part('search-listings');
 return;
}`
This checks if there is a search query or rather, it checks to see if 'search-listings' is one of the GET variables set in the query. If so, it loads the search-results page

Comment: Does that make sense? Please let me know if there is anything else that is unclear. Can't thank you enough for your help!